# Assign geometry_msgs::position in one line

Tags: geometry-msgs, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I am struggling with a really easy problem. I declared :

```
geometry_msgs::Pose pose_msg;
```

I am trying to assign x y z coordinates in one line instead of doing:

```
pose_msg.position.x = 0.0;
pose_msg.position.y = 0.0;
pose_msg.position.z = 0.0;
```

I would like to do something like:

```
pose_msg.position = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

Sorry if the question has been already asked but for me, it was hard to find an answer online.

Thanks in advance for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282859/assign-geometry_msgs::position-in-one-line/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the default messages, this is not supported.

With the merge of [ros/gencpp#32](https://github.com/ros/gencpp/pull/32) this is now possible (after `gencpp` version `0.6.0` has been released), but will need custom code.

See [wiki/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes - Customizing generated message headers for C++](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes#Customizing_generated_message_headers_for_C.2B-.2B-) for more info on this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2018-02-15**:
Great, thanks a lot for your help.